# Is it possible to get duration of the remote audio file without downloading it?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have an Url of the remote audio file. I need to build data for adapter list with track details. Here is this part of code

```
    Log.d("audioURL", audio.getUrl());
    MediaPlayer tmpMedia;
    tmpMedia = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), Uri.parse(audio.getUrl()));
    holder.txtDuration.setDuration(tmpMedia.getDuration()/1000);
    tmpMedia.release();
```

But it works too slowly. LogCat writes something like this:

```
15:05:51.783: D/audioURL(776): http://cs4859.vk.me/u14195999/audios/0cbd695ddf50.mp3
15:05:51.783: D/MediaPlayer(776): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
15:05:53.813: D/audioURL(776): http://cs4859.vk.me/u14195999/audios/0cbd695ddf50.mp3
15:05:53.823: D/MediaPlayer(776): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
15:05:55.373: D/audioURL(776): http://cs4859.vk.me/u14195999/audios/0cbd695ddf50.mp3
15:05:55.383: D/MediaPlayer(776): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
15:05:58.143: D/audioURL(776): http://cs1626.vk.me/u149968/audios/04298447cd3c.mp3
15:05:58.153: D/MediaPlayer(776): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

...and so on. So, my playlist of about 30 tracks initializes with about 7 minutes.

I guess, the [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class method `getDuration()` sequentially downloads these tracks (or some parts of them) to get their durations.

Is there a way to get these durations quickly, without downloading tracks?

Halim Qarroum, it seems to be a correct way, but I have some troubles with `MediaMetadataRetriever` class.

Here is my code above:

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 10){
        holder.txtDuration.setDuration(audio.getTrackDuration());
    } else {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Log.d("URI", Uri.parse(audio.getUrl()).toString());
        mRetriever.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(audio.getUrl()));
        String s = mRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
        holder.txtDuration.setDuration(Long.parseLong(s));
        mRetriever.release();
    }
```

Application terminates in `mRetriever.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(audio.getUrl()));` because of `IllegalArgumentException`. The `audio.getURl()` string is `http://cs4859.vk.me/u14195999/audios/134dfe90d1ec.mp3`.

Why the exception occurs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dheeb posted a well detailed answer. However, `ID3 tags` are not always present in an mp3 file. Instead of looking for these tags, which will force you to limit this method to mp3 files, you could use the [`MediaMetadataRetriever`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html) class which comes with the Android framework.

This class can give you several metadata from certain types of audio/video files, one of this information, is the duration. This method has the advantage to be standard, as it comes with the Android SDK and is not limited to one audio format.

From the Android developers related page :

> MediaMetadataRetriever class provides a unified interface for
>   retrieving frame and meta data from an input media file.

A trivial example of code using this class :

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(your_data_source);
String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
long timeInmillisec = Long.parseLong( time );
long duration = timeInmillisec / 1000;
long hours = duration / 3600;
long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);
```

Comment: Sounds good, but the exception occurs ( See my comment above in my post

Comment: An exception occurs in the second line  mRetriever.setDataSource(getContext(), Uri.parse(audio.getUrl()));

This line throws IllegalArgumentException. As per description of the class the  setDataSource (Context context, Uri uri) method  throws IllegalArgumentException if the Uri is invalid. But my Uri seems to be a valid one - for example http://cs4859.vk.me/u14195999/audios/134dfe90d1ec.mp3

Comment: Accessing to your URI throws a `404` error. Try using your browser. You do not have to use `Uri.parse()`, you can pass a string directly.

Comment: I can access to my Uri without any problems from my location. May be, you have some firewall or access-list restrictions? Of course I tried to use `setDataSource (String path)` form, but unfortunately with the same effect (

Comment: I don't have any restrictions regarding internet browsing. Maybe the media you're trying to access is protected and you need to set a security token (cookie ?)

Comment: But `MediaPlayer.getDuration()` works without any errors and exceptions. But it takes much time. The media does not seem to be protected, I can download and play it without any limitations.

Comment: That's odd. Can you update the code you've posted ? And post the `logcat` as well ?

Comment: The first approach in my question works correctly, but too slowly. See my question above. After logging `Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side` the application gets track duration correctly.

Comment: This is not an error message, it is a debug message stating that the uri does not point to a local location (e.g SDCARD) but to a remote one (content located on the network).

Comment: How come it is an accepted answer???? the setDataSource is just not for remote file its for external file in sd card. totally wrong answer

Comment: It is the accepted answer since it is correct and accurate, I have been using this exemple myself. It is true though that on some version/variants of android remote uris are notre properly handled, there is another thread on SO that talks about this.

Answer (score 8):

There was bug related to MediaMetadataRetriever. 
You could try,

```
 metaRetreiver.setDataSource("<remoteUrl>", new HashMap<String, String>());
```

Answer (score 6):

## I'll assume mp3 since "Audio File" is a blanket phrase.

### Method 1: fetch ID3 tag

#### Variant 1: 3rd party library

You will need to look at the ID3 tags in the mp3 file.
Unless you keep track of the metadata you want somewhere else.

To specifically get the Track length of the file you will need to look into the ID3 metadata tag for sure, specifically the 'TRCK' frame of the tag.

To only download the ID3 Tag part, you must first download the ID3 header part of the file.

This [website](http://www.id3.org/Developer_Information) contains very specific information about the ID3 Tag format.  You will need to look at the version number of the ID3 Tag and then, based on that, you will need to find the information regarding how long the ID3 Tag is.  Then, you must download the WHOLE tag because the frames are not in any specific order.

Then you should be able to use a third party library to find the TRCK frame and its data.

#### Variant 2: HTTP Hack

For ID3v2 tags, grab the start of the file. (It's possible for ID3v2 frames to be elsewhere, but in practice they're always there.) You can't tell how long the tag is going to be in advance. For text-only tags you're likely to find the information you want in the first 512-1024 bytes. Unfortunately more and more MP3s have embedded ‘album art’ pictures, which can be much longer; try to pick an ID3 library that will gracefully ignore truncated ID3 information.

ID3v1 tags are located at the end of the file. Again you can't tell how long they're going to be. And of course you don't know in advance whether the file has ID3v1 tags, ID3v2 tags, both or neither. Generally these days ID3v2 is a better bet though.

To read part of a file through HTTP you need the [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.2) header. This too is not supported everywhere.

### Method 2: Estimation

File size you can get with an HTTP HEAD request. Duration meaning playing time in seconds, cannot be gotten without fetching the entire file. You can *guess*, by fetching the first few MP3 frames, looking at their bitrate, and assuming that the rest of the file has the same bitrate, but given the popularity of Variable Bit-Rate encoding the likelihood this will be close to accurate is quite low.

> ID3 tags can in theory contain information that might allow you to
>   guess the length better, in the ASPI and ETCO tags. But in practice
>   these are very rarely present.

***Credits***

> Credits go to various authors on SO and the interwebs, ofcourse the guy on the first floor in my head.